# Dataframe manupulation in pyspark

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have to do data processing in pyspark and am looking for the best performance possible. 
I have a table with around 5000 columns and need to do data manipulation

columnlist has the list of columns required to be processed, and sql_df is a dataframe with 5000 columns are 10K rows

---

```
for col_name in columnlist:
    colname_new = col_name + "_new"
    sql_df = sql_df.withColumn(col_name, lit(10000))
    sql_df = sql_df.drop(col_name)
    sql_df = sql_df.withColumnRenamed(col_name + "_new", col_name)
```

---

the above takes more than 3 hours to process which is totally unacceptable 
Is there a better way for this?

i also tried the below which gave error

```
   sql_df = spark.sql("Select * from filtered_table")

    def f(col_name): 
        global sql_df
        colname_new = col_name + "_new"
        sql_df = sql_df.withColumn(col_name, lit('10000'))
        sql_df = sql_df.drop(col_name)
        sql_df = sql_df.withColumnRenamed(col_name + "_new", col_name)  

    collist = sc.parallelize(filtered_df.columns).foreach(f)
```

Thanks in advance 
Maxx

Comment: What exactly is the data manipulation step here? I cannot seem to make any sense of it

Comment: Did you try it with Google colab?

Comment: This is a data cleaning process. Where we update existing data based on data in other columns. 1 Table will be cleaning rules while other is data. i need to loop through cleaning rules and update data based on cleaning rules.